# Can createUserWithEmailAndPassword called be multiple times?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm asking this because I want display a message to the user only once:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val isUserNew = authResult.additionalUserInfo!!.isNewUser!!
                if(isUserNew) {
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, task.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
```

So can isUserNew be false? Or it's always true since createUserWithEmailAndPassword is only called once? And I don't even need to check that.

Comment: Did you read https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth?
Why do you want to call it more than once? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @TheincredibleJan I don't want to call it more than once. I was asking if it's possible? I only need to know if that check is redundant, since I call createUserWithEmailAndPassword only onec. Right after that I call signInWithEmailAndPassword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AdditionalUserInfo` is also used in other auth methods so, `isUserNew` is there for convenience.

If user deleted the app and signed in again, or logged in via Google on second device for example, `isUserNew` will be false. But in this particular case it will always be true.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. If the user uninstalls and then installs the app, if I try to call createUserWithEmailAndPassword it says that user is already there. That's why I asked.

Comment: 1. After you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` the `isUserNew` property will always be true. 2. When the user signs in afterwards, `isUserNew` will be false. 3. Additional calls to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` with the same email address will fail.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So when I call createUserWithEmailAndPassword, there is no need to check that if the user is new, right? He's always new inside the callback, is that correct?

Comment: Correct: you just created the user, so they're new.